# React native DatePickerAndroid clear option

Tags: react-native

I'm using the native DatePickerAndroid for editing a date field in my react-native app.

I would like to know if there is any support for adding a 'clear' button to the native date picker that will close the datepicker and return an empty date - in order to be able to clear the date in the input field.

I've attached a screenshot of the native android date picker opened from a regular `<input/>` with type `date` in chrome. As you can see there is a 'clear' button - exactly what I'm looking for!

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Sanderfish Take a look at my answer, it works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this question was previously answered by *ufxmeng*, but his answer was lately deleted (I don't know why...).

His solution was to create a custom `AndroidDatePicker` module, mostly copied from the original `DatePicker` Module created by **React Native**, with slight changes for adding a CLEAR button.

He put together a github repo holding all files that need to be added/changed to accomplish this. Basically the changes you'll need are [here](https://github.com/ufxmeng/CustomDatePicker/tree/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/customdatepicker) and [here](https://github.com/ufxmeng/CustomDatePicker/blob/master/src/DatePickerAndroid.js).

But note that the original CLEAR button added in that repo doesn't fully match the needs pointed out in my question (see this [issue](https://github.com/ufxmeng/CustomDatePicker/issues/1)).

So I've changed some of the code to make it work the way I expected. You could see the changes I made in this [pull request](https://github.com/ufxmeng/CustomDatePicker/pull/2)

It works great for me!

Comment: Thank you so much for replying and adding this! I'll see if I can get it working tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else needs this, I forked the original repo of `ufxmeng` and added `Clear` button functionality for `TimePicker` as well:

https://github.com/sladek-jan/CustomDatePicker